# Cassandra select not stable using datastax driver

Tags: cassandra, apache-beam, datastax, cassandra-3.0, feast

```
Versions:
  com.datastax.oss
      -java-driver-core:4.5.0
      -java-driver-query-builder:4.5.0
      -java-driver-mapper-runtime:4.5.0
  cassandra:3.11.5 docker image
  jdk 11.1
```

I'm running a deployment of [feast](https://github.com/gojek/feast/) that I've modified to use cassandra as a backend low latency serving db for machine learning features. I'm sucessfully writing and reading rows, but the read is inconsistent with respect to results returned. Sometimes the payloads are empty and I don't know why. I have already tried updating to the latest datastax driver and coordinating time using ntp/time.google.com. I've also tried to change the consistency of write to ALL and read to LOCAL_ONE/LOCAL_QUOROM, without success. I'm really struggling to figure out why select isn't consistent. Any insight would be great! :) Here is the process:
I write the rows into cassandra using CassandraIO

```java
  @Override
  public Future<Void> saveAsync(CassandraMutation entityClass) {
    return mapper.saveAsync(
        entityClass,
        Option.timestamp(entityClass.getWriteTime()),
        Option.ttl(entityClass.getTtl()),
        Option.consistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM),
        Option.tracing(true));
  }
```

This seems to successfully map rows into my cassandra cluster, which I then query in my application as follows

```java
    List<InetSocketAddress> contactPoints =
         Arrays.stream(cassandraConfig.getBootstrapHosts().split(","))
            .map(h -> new InetSocketAddress(h, cassandraConfig.getPort()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    CqlSession session =
        CqlSession.builder()
            .addContactPoints(contactPoints)
            .withLocalDatacenter(storeProperties.getCassandraDcName())
                .build();
    ....
    PreparedStatement query =
        session.prepare(
            String.format(
                "SELECT entities, feature, value, WRITETIME(value) as writetime FROM %s.%s WHERE entities = ?",
                keyspace, tableName));
    session.execute(
            query
                .bind(key)
                .setTracing(true)
                .setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_QUORUM)));
```

My issue is that there doesn't seem to be consistent selects happening. I have been recording various bits for a while now and for example here are two select queries, with the same coordinator, one succeeded, then after that the subsequent select fails to return results.

```sh
cqlsh> select * from system_traces.sessions where session_id=be023400-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36;

 session_id                           | client        | command | coordinator   | duration | parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | request                     | started_at
--------------------------------------+---------------+---------+---------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------
 be023400-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36 | xx.xx.xxx.189 |   QUERY | xx.xx.xxx.158 |    41313 | {'bound_var_0_entities': '''ml_project/test_test_entity:1:entity2_uuid=TenderGreens_8755fff7|entity1_uuid=Zach_Yang_fe7fea92''', 'consistency_level': 'LOCAL_QUORUM', 'page_size': '5000', 'query': 'SELECT entities, feature, value, WRITETIME(value) as writetime FROM feast.feature_store WHERE entities = ?', 'serial_consistency_level': 'SERIAL'} | Execute CQL3 prepared query | 2020-03-19 20:18:05.760000+0000
select event_id, activity, source_elapsed, thread from system_traces.events where session_id=be023400-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36;
  event_id  |  activity  |  source_elapsed  |  thread
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  be0652b0-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Read-repair  DC_LOCAL  |  27087  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  be0679c0-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  reading  data  from  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  28034  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  be06a0d0-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Sending  READ  message  to  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  28552  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/xx.xx.xxx.161-Small
  be06a0d1-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  reading  digest  from  /xx.xx.xxx.162  |  28595  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  be06a0d2-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  28598  |  ReadStage-3
  be06a0d3-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  28689  |  ReadStage-3
  be06a0d4-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  reading  digest  from  /xx.xx.xx.138  |  28852  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  be06a0d5-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Sending  READ  message  to  /xx.xx.xxx.162  |  28904  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/xx.xx.xxx.162-Small
  be06a0d6-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  56  |  28937  |  ReadStage-3
  be06a0d7-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  reading  digest  from  /xx.xx.xxx.171  |  28983  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  be06a0d8-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  29020  |  ReadStage-3
  be06a0d9-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Sending  READ  message  to  cassandra-feature-store-1.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xx.138  |  29071  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-feature-store-1.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xx.138-Small
  be06a0da-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  29181  |  ReadStage-3
  be06a0db-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Sending  READ  message  to  cassandra-feature-store-0.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.171  |  29201  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-feature-store-0.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xx.171-Small
  be06c7e0-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  READ  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  33  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.158
  be06c7e0-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  READ  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  34  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.158
  be06c7e0-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  READ  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  29  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.158
  be06c7e0-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  READ  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  44  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.158
  be06c7e0-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  29273  |  ReadStage-3
  be06c7e1-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  389  |  ReadStage-1
  be06c7e1-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  513  |  ReadStage-1
  be06c7e1-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Skipped  0/4  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  29342  |  ReadStage-3
  be06c7e2-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  457  |  ReadStage-1
  be06c7e3-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  620  |  ReadStage-1
  be06c7e4-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  659  |  ReadStage-1
  be06c7e5-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  677  |  ReadStage-1
  be06c7e6-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Skipped  0/3  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  695  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef0-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  1039  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef0-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  372  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef0-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  583  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef0-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  454  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef0-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  30372  |  ReadStage-3
  be06eef1-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Read  16  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  1125  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef1-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  493  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef1-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  703  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef1-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  530  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef1-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Read  16  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  30484  |  ReadStage-3
  be06eef2-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Enqueuing  response  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1155  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef2-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  56  |  721  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef2-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  740  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef2-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  56  |  655  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef3-6a1e-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Sending  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  to  cassandra-feature-store-2.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1492  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-feature-store-2.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.158-Small
  be06eef3-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  780  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef3-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Skipped  0/2  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  761  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef3-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  686  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef4-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  815  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef4-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  1320  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef4-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  705  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef5-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  839  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef5-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Read  16  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  1495  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef5-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  720  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef6-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Skipped  0/4  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  871  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef6-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Enqueuing  response  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1554  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef6-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Skipped  0/4  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  738  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef7-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  1157  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef8-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Read  16  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  1296  |  ReadStage-1
  be06eef9-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Enqueuing  response  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1325  |  ReadStage-1
  be071600-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  1592  |  ReadStage-1
  be071600-6a1e-11ea-8b1a-e5aa876f7d0d  |  Sending  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  to  cassandra-feature-store-2.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1783  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-feature-store-2.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.158-Small
  be071600-6a1e-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Sending  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1484  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/xx.xx.xxx.158-Small
  be071600-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  31525  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.161
  be071601-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Read  16  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  1754  |  ReadStage-1
  be071601-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Processing  response  from  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  31650  |  RequestResponseStage-4
  be071602-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Enqueuing  response  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1796  |  ReadStage-1
  be071602-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xx.138  |  31795  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xx.138
  be071603-6a1e-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Sending  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1973  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/xx.xx.xxx.158-Small
  be071603-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Processing  response  from  /xx.xx.xx.138  |  31872  |  RequestResponseStage-4
  be071604-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.162  |  31918  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.162
  be071605-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Processing  response  from  /xx.xx.xxx.162  |  32047  |  RequestResponseStage-4
  be073d10-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.171  |  32688  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xx.171
  be073d11-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Processing  response  from  /xx.xx.xxx.171  |  32827  |  RequestResponseStage-2
  be073d12-6a1e-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Initiating  read-repair  |  32985  |  RequestResponseStage-2
```

Failure:

```sh
cqlsh> select * from system_traces.sessions where session_id=472551e0-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36;

 session_id                           | client        | command | coordinator   | duration | parameters                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              | request                     | started_at
--------------------------------------+---------------+---------+---------------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------
 472551e0-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36 | xx.xx.xxx.189 |   QUERY | xx.xx.xxx.158 |     3044 | {'bound_var_0_entities': '''ml_project/test_test_entity:1:entity1_uuid=Zach_Yang_fe7fea92|entity2_uuid=TenderGreens_8755fff7''', 'consistency_level': 'LOCAL_QUORUM', 'page_size': '5000', 'query': 'SELECT entities, feature, value, WRITETIME(value) as writetime FROM feast.feature_store WHERE entities = ?', 'serial_consistency_level': 'SERIAL'} | Execute CQL3 prepared query | 2020-03-19 20:21:55.838000+0000
cqlsh> select event_id, activity, source_elapsed, thread from system_traces.events where session_id=472551e0-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36;
  event_id  |  activity  |  source_elapsed  |  thread
--------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  472578f0-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  READ  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  18  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.158
  472578f0-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  reading  digest  from  /xx.xx.xxx.138  |  619  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  472578f1-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  708  |  ReadStage-2
  472578f2-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  reading  digest  from  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  755  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  472578f3-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  768  |  ReadStage-2
  472578f4-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Sending  READ  message  to  cassandra-feature-store-1.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.138  |  836  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-feature-store-1.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.138-Small
  472578f5-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  56  |  859  |  ReadStage-2
  472578f6-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  speculating  read  retry  on  /xx.xx.xx.171  |  862  |  Native-Transport-Requests-1
  472578f7-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Sending  READ  message  to  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  893  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/xx.xx.xxx.161-Small
  472578f8-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  903  |  ReadStage-2
  472578f9-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  929  |  ReadStage-2
  472578fa-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Sending  READ  message  to  cassandra-feature-store-0.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xx.171  |  982  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-feature-store-0.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xx.171-Small
  472578fb-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  996  |  ReadStage-2
  472578fc-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Skipped  0/4  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  1039  |  ReadStage-2
  472578fd-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  1227  |  ReadStage-2
  472578fe-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Read  0  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  1282  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a000-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  226  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a000-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  READ  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  12  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.158
  4725a000-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  READ  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  15  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.158
  4725a001-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  297  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a001-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  258  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a001-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Executing  single-partition  query  on  feature_store  |  230  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a002-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  397  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a002-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  327  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a002-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Acquiring  sstable  references  |  297  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a003-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  433  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a003-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  56  |  451  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a003-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  56  |  439  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a004-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  450  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a004-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  512  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a004-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  55  |  492  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a005-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Skipped  0/3  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  466  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a005-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  570  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a005-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  54  |  513  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a006-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  648  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a006-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  606  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a006-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Bloom  filter  allows  skipping  sstable  41  |  526  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a007-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Read  0  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  708  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a007-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Skipped  0/4  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  631  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a007-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Skipped  0/4  non-slice-intersecting  sstables,  included  0  due  to  tombstones  |  542  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a008-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Enqueuing  response  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  727  |  ReadStage-2
  4725a008-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  700  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a009-6a1f-11ea-80ad-dffaf3fb56b4  |  Sending  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  to  cassandra-feature-store-2.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.158  |  838  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-cassandra-feature-store-2.cassandra-feature-store.team-data/xx.xx.xxx.158-Small
  4725a009-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Read  0  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  756  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a00a-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Enqueuing  response  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  772  |  ReadStage-1
  4725a00b-6a1f-11ea-8d2e-c5837edad3d1  |  Sending  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  914  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/xx.xx.xxx.158-Small
  4725c710-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Merged  data  from  memtables  and  0  sstables  |  845  |  ReadStage-1
  4725c710-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  2327  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.161
  4725c711-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Read  0  live  rows  and  0  tombstone  cells  |  905  |  ReadStage-1
  4725c711-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Processing  response  from  /xx.xx.xxx.161  |  2443  |  RequestResponseStage-2
  4725c712-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Enqueuing  response  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  929  |  ReadStage-1
  4725c712-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xxx.138  |  2571  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xxx.138
  4725c713-6a1f-11ea-8693-577fec389856  |  Sending  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  to  /xx.xx.xxx.158  |  1023  |  MessagingService-Outgoing-/xx.xx.xxx.158-Small
  4725c713-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Processing  response  from  /xx.xx.xxx.138  |  2712  |  RequestResponseStage-2
  4725c714-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  REQUEST_RESPONSE  message  received  from  /xx.xx.xx.171  |  2725  |  MessagingService-Incoming-/xx.xx.xx.171
  4725c715-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Processing  response  from  /xx.xx.xx.171  |  2797  |  RequestResponseStage-2
  4725c716-6a1f-11ea-97ca-6b8bbe3a2a36  |  Initiating  read-repair  |  2855  |  RequestResponseStage-2
```

Keyspace info

```
cqlsh> describe keyspace feast;

CREATE KEYSPACE feast WITH replication = {'class': 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'stage-us-west1': '5'}  AND durable_writes = true;

CREATE TABLE feast.feature_store (
    entities text,
    feature text,
    value blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (entities, feature)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (feature ASC)
    AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
    AND caching = {'keys': 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition': 'NONE'}
    AND comment = ''
    AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold': '32', 'min_threshold': '4'}
    AND compression = {'chunk_length_in_kb': '64', 'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
    AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
    AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
    AND default_time_to_live = 0
    AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
    AND max_index_interval = 2048
    AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
    AND min_index_interval = 128
    AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
    AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Hm both of those look like traces for successful requests to me, the first one was slower and returned rows, the second one was faster and returned 0 rows. Are you sure there were rows in the database to be selected for the second read? By the way, as an optimization, you should be saving your prepared statement somewhere and re using it, rather than re-creating it every time you read.

Comment: Yep, I prepare my statement earlier, sorry the code was copy pasted to be illustrative. I'm sure that there is data because both queries ran for the same bound prepared statement, with the same id, and the empty query was made after the populated one. I can add that to the body of the question

Comment: Added the output of system_traces.sessions for the ids, the failed query happened after the sucessful one

Comment: Specific to Feast, what's the maxAge of the feature set you're ingesting and querying? It gets used as TTL, so let's first rule out that :-) Could you also post your `DESCRIBE KEYSPACE`?

Comment: `grpc_cli call feature-store-core-client.domain.net:6565 ListFeatureSets "filter {project: 'ml_project', feature_set_name: 'test_test_entity', feature_set_version: 'latest'}"` shows `    max_age {
      seconds: 86400
    }
`

Comment: Maybe Feast inserts with a TLL?

Comment: I had too many stores, I didn't quite realize that when you deploy a online/batch service, it autogens stores, and I was manually adding one for bq and serving. This caused duplicate rows to be written at the sameish time to cassandra, which I haven't quite isolated what was going wrong, but I'm assuming there are tokens, upsert times, rings, etc that can all be discombobulated by this. I want to isolate what's exactly going wrong or have someone who knows what this would cause to answer though, but I think I'm seeing vast improvement after deployment of the change.

Comment: @phact It does, the insert is the snippet at the top, part of a pr, that I and others contributed to https://github.com/gojek/feast/blob/356332326001ae37e9fe14dc6c2260d359cb1765/ingestion/src/main/java/feast/ingestion/transform/CassandraMutationMapper.java#L59

Comment: So are we thinking we can write this off to TTL + internal write time implications? Let me know if you have any remaining c* related questions.